# Finding $Ext^1(V_a,V_b)$ and classifying 2-dimensional representations of an algebra

Tags: representation-theory

Consider $A=\mathbb C[x]$ an representations $V_a,V_b$ of dimension one defined by $\rho(x)=a,\rho(x)=b$ respectively. We want to find $\operatorname{Ext}^1(V_a,V_b)$ and classify the 2-dimensional representations.

The solution I have says that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(V_a,V_b)=0$ if $a\neq b$ and $\mathbb C$ if $a=b$ by computing cocycles and coboundaries and then proceeds to say that 2-dimensional representations are of the form : $V_a\oplus V_a$, $V_a\oplus V_b$ $a\neq b$ and $U_a\cong C[x]/<(x-a)^2>$.

I can understand how to get $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ but I don't understand how we get the 2-dim. representations from it. Why for example would $\operatorname{Ext}^1(V_a,V_b)=0$ imply that we have that $V_a\oplus V_b$ is indeed a representation fo dimension 2 ?

And why should 2-dim. representations be obtained by studying an extension like this. Can't we imagine one which is not such an extension ?